# Add multiple NSSlider to view programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, slider

I'm new to objective C and Cocoa, but I have managed to add a slider into some views etc. I got that.

I want to add multiple sliders with code, and I tried it with a for loop and a array. It didnt work, but here is the Code I tried:

```
NSMutableArray* myarray;
for (int i = 0; i<5; i = i+30) {
    [myarray addObject:[[NSSlider alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(15+i, 15, 30, 200)]];

}



for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    [firstView addSubview:[myarray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}
```

(wanted to show them 30 apart, but doesnt matter it didnt work. Then I tried this if its even working "through" an array

```
[myarray addObject:[[NSSlider alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(15, 15, 30, 200)]];
[firstView addSubview:[myarray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

I tried to show only one slider. Doesnt work either.

But this works:

```
    [firstView addSubview:[[NSSlider alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(45, 15, 30, 200)]];
```

Why? And what is the right way to add multiple sliders/buttons/whatever doesnt really matter to add to a view dynamically? The real Idea is to get Data from CoreData and for each entry in CoreData it should Display a slider. (But thats far away)

I need some tips and tricks! Thanks in advance guys!

BTW when I try to init the array this way:

```
NSMutableArray* myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

the views dont load (firstView especially because this view is black)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `for` statement is totally wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i = i+30)
```

It will enter the loop only once.
That's probably why you're not getting all the sliders you want.

Comment: haha, thanks a lot! I was kinda blind I think, didnt even thought about that after changing it from i++ to +30

Comment: @bennibeef: You may want to change it back and use a multiply-add instead: `rect.origin.x = fma(sliderWidth + sliderGap, i, sliderGap)` (equivalent to, but potentially more precise than, `rect.origin.x = ((sliderWidth + sliderGap) * i) + sliderGap`).